# Adding a modifier array along a curve is providing inconsistent results

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I am using Blender 2.93.3 (on Mac OS 11.5.1) and am running into some odd behaviors.  The goal is to have Dominos collapse and spell a word.

[image]

The first image shows the capital "r" and it is acceptable.  I tried this with a second curve (el) second image, but had to use completely different constant offset settings to get it to follow the curve, but the items are way too close.  Oddly, changing the settings to match the first one creates a bizarre abomination that scared me.

Suggestions are always welcome.

[image: Good Capital R]

[image: semi decent]

[image: very crazy path]

Comment: I didn't get it all sorted out, but you need to apply your scales and rotations on your curves and Dominoes in order to get things to work.

Answer (score 0):

- Apply the rotation of both the curve and the domino
- In Edit mode, rotate the mesh of your domino to align it with the global orientation
- Put the domino at the same point as the curve's origin
- In the *Array* modifier, choose only one *Offset* axis
- Find the right *Deform Axis* in the *Curve* modifier